# How to programmatically restart a Openshift POD when an exception occurs

Tags: openshift

Is there a way to programatically restart PODs when an exception occurs.Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use case for Liveness probes: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/applications/application-health.html

Applying a Liveness probe to your pod/deployment will perform the defined check (HTTP/Exec/TCP) against the pod. If it errors out, it will automatically trigger a restart of the pod.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to check for Kerberos authentiction part of liveness check?

Comment: Typically, the recommended way of testing liveness for _external_ systems is to create an endpoint in your application, something like `/kerberos_liveness`. You can then perform an HTTP liveness check on that endpoint. It would be up to your application to determine if kerberos authentication is successful or not and return an appropriate HTTP code. Alternatively, you could include a helper script with your application, that you would call from an `Exec` liveness check.